# WineHQ starting services

Tags: wine

I get an error when I try to open a service on Linux WineHQ 7.0

kernelbase:AppPolicyGetProcessTerminationMethod
or
Failed to initialize BattlEye Service: Driver Load Error (1053)

Comment: Ubuntu version 20.04 LTS

Comment: https://github.com/ValveSoftware/Proton/issues/30